# PySpark: Job aborts due to stage failure, but resetting max size isn't recognized

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm attempting to display a dataframe in PySpark after reading the files in using a function/subroutine.  Reading the files in works greatly, but it's the display that's not working.  Actually, due to lazy evaluation, this may not be true.

I get this error

```
SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 29381 tasks (4.0 GB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (4.0 GB)
```

so I do what was suggested https://forums.databricks.com/questions/66/how-do-i-work-around-this-error-when-using-rddcoll.html

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "8g")
sqlContext.getConf("spark.driver.maxResultSize")
```

however, the bizarre part is, this *gives the same error back* when I re-run the `display(df)` command.

It's like Spark is just ignoring my commands.

I've tried increasing the number of workers and making both the worker type and driver type larger, but neither of these fixed anything.

How can I get this to work?  or is this a bug in Databricks/Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on your code and partitioning of the code with respect to the cluster size. Increasing spark.driver.maxResultSize is the first option to solve the problem and eventually look for a permanent solution to modify the code or design. Please do avoid collecting more data to driver node.

**OR**

You need to change this parameter in the cluster configuration. Go into the cluster settings, under Advanced select spark and paste **spark.driver.maxResultSize 0** (for unlimited) or whatever the value suits you. Using 0 is not recommended. You should optimize the job by re partitioning.

[image]

For more details, refer "[Spark Configurations - Application Properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties)".

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.